# How to stop TField.Origin from getting reset

Tags: delphi, tfield

I use the TField.origin property to dynamically build a where clause for SQL queries.

So if I have a query such as;

```
select
  p.firstname,
  p.lastname,
  g.description
from
  people p
  inner join groups g
```

I can set the origin of the firstname field to;

```
FirstNameField.origin = 'p.firstname';
```

Then use this in the where clause of dynamic queries such as;

```
SQLWhere = 'where ' + FirstNameField.origin + ' = ''' + MyValue + ''' ';
```

(obviously i have additional code to prevent against SQL injection).

I do this all the time and it works great. However when trying to track down a bug, I noticed I have one dataset that keeps reseting the value of the origin for example back to;

```
people.firstname
```

instead of;

```
p.firstname
```

I tracked it down to when the dataset is closed and then reopened. However I do this all the time, so I can't understand why one dataset has different behaviour.

My question is how can I prevent the origin value from getting reset?

Comment: Why don't you just use parameters insted of additional code to prevent injection?

Comment: What database components do you use?

Comment: I'm using the TIBDataset component.

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking, and I really don't know why the property is being reset, since [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Origin) states it's only assigned at design time (maybe TIBDataSet has different behaviour); but `TField.Origin` is supposed to be in the format `TableName.FIeldName`. Maybe you should just not use aliases in your dynamic queries.

Comment: That's probably how i will solve it. Annoying though because the alias keep the SQL tidy. I only used a simple example but in the real application the can sometimes be over 60 fields and table names are long because this is large database with 100s of tables.

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Answer (score 3):

The  code below is from D7's IBCustomDataSet unit (the code is more complex in later
XEx versions).

It's this code which sets the `Origin` property of an IBX TField.

TIBCustomDataSet.CreateFields will get called when the dataset calls its `InternalOpen`
method if its `FDefaultFields` field is True.  It will be True if on entry to `InternalOpen`
the `FieldCount` of the dataset is zero. `FieldCount` will be zero if no fields have
been created in advance, either in user-code or in the IDE using the Fields editor
on the dataset.  `InternalOpen` is called by TDataSet.Open via its `OpenCursor` method.

So the way to avoid 'CreateFields' being executed and the dataset fields' `Origin`
properties being reset as a consequence is to use either of these methods (IDE or user code)
to create the fields prior to opening the dataset.  In other words, if you set the `Origin` property by either of these methods, that should avoid it getting reset.

```
procedure TIBCustomDataSet.CreateFields;
var
  FieldAliasName, RelationName : String;
  i : Integer;
  f : TField;
begin
  inherited;
  for i := 0 to FQSelect.Current.Count - 1 do
    with FQSelect.Current[i].Data^ do
    begin
      { Get the field name }
      SetString(FieldAliasName, aliasname, aliasname_length);
      SetString(RelationName, relname, relname_length);
      f := FindField(FieldAliasname);
      if Assigned(f) then
      begin
        if (RelationName <> '') and (FieldAliasName <> '') then
          f.Origin := RelationName + '.' + FieldAliasName;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

**Update**  The implementation of TIBCustomDataSet.InternalOpen was evidently changed between XE4 and XE6 so that CreateFields is now called unconditionally (i.e. regardless of whether DefaultFields is True).  Therefore, having already-existing TFields will not avoid CreateFields being called and therefore the Origin properties being reset.

Comment: You mean you're working with XE8?  I don't think it makes any difference - the code in CreateFields is more complex, but the principle is the same.

Comment: The same code from delphi XE8 checks the FieldName not the FieldAliasName, before setting the origin. Could this be a bug? I dare not change it back as there are other changes and I don't want to break it.

Comment: ok, i've read your answer again. I am creating the fields in the IDE and setting the origin there. So I would expect that the fields exist before TDataset.Open is called. But maybe for some reason it's not.

Comment: Well, you can easily enough put a breakpoint in TIBCustomDataSet.CreateFields and see whether (and why) it's getting called at run-time.

Comment: ok, the breakpoint verifies that CreateFields is getting executed. I can see that my origin is ok at that point, but CreateFields overwrites it. But how do I tell why CreateFields is being called? thanks for your help btw, much appreciated.

Comment: found the stack trace. InternalOpen always calls CreateFields. InternalOpen is called because TDataset.OpenCursor finds it's InfoQuery parameter = false. The reason that is false is because TDataset.SetActive calls OpenCursor without passing a parameter.So now i'm wondering if this is an embarcadero bug?

Comment: for info delphi 2006 works fine. however, I can't debug delphi 2006. the breakpoints go green with a cross through them.

Comment: It looks deliberate, because TIBCustomDataSet.InternalOpen unconditionally calls CreateFields in XE8.  So I guess you need to save your Origin settings before the dataset and restore them after the dataset is opened.

Comment: Well at least we've tracked down the cause. My problem is a have a large application with around 300 forms / queries. bummer. Embarcadero strikes again.

Comment: I checked and the change to InternalOpen is in XE6 but not XE4 (I don't have XE5 installed).  However, note that InternalOpen is virual, so you could derive a TIBCustomDataSet descendant and re-instate the previous way it worked or, as a last resort, copy IBX.IBCustomDataSet to your project directory and modify its InternalOpen in that.  Personally, I would ask in the Emb newsgroups whether the change was intentional or not - the author of the IBX components is a regular contributor there.